# git fsck shows duplicateEntries but I'm able to git pull and push

Tags: git, fsck

I have a repository where `git fsck` command gives me the following error:

```
error in tree b2b510c83ea553c587ebe5bc160e92cb7888393a: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
```

However, I am able to push and pull with this repo. so where exactly this duplicate error can impact me?

I'm asking because I saw [git tree contains duplicate file entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931954/git-tree-contains-duplicate-file-entries) thread where it clearly interrupts the user.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the error message correctly, in some tree (i.e., a directory at some point in the past) the same file (contents) is mentioned twice. Not in itself fatal, but it probably means something is messed up in your past history.

What I'd do: Clone the repository to a new copy (locally; that should untangle any nonsense in the new copy; check!), **back it up** before fiddling around! In the suspect repository use low-level git tools like `git show` to look around and see if you can find out what is wrong (and perhaps fix it). Check the options of `git fsck`.